# who knows the Google Cloud Storage JSON API authorization turn around time?

Tags: json, google-api, google-cloud-storage

Does anyone have a sense about how long it takes for Google to approve access to the JSON API for cloud storage? It's been two days now since I filled out the request form, and I have still not even seen an email confirming my request.

My request was for 500 API hits per day - I am just doing exploratory code development at the moment for a product prototype.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually within a few days; I generally batch requests when I respond.

However, if you provide a bad e-mail address or a bad description (e.g., "asdfjklm") then the turnaround time will be infinite, as I cannot and will not (respectively) respond.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, just got your email.